# How can I make a div grow downwards only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent div that has a child div centered inside it. What I want is that when I click on the child div it grows downwards only, not both upwards and downwards.

The two divs before I click:

[image]

The result I get when I click on div 2:

[image]

The result I'm looking for when I click on div 2:

[image]

```js
let div2 = document.querySelector("#div2");
div2.addEventListener("click", e => {
  div2.style.height = "300px";
})
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: red solid medium;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#div2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  outline: blue solid medium;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did your parent always have 200px for height ? If so, if you want 50px margin from top, dont align center your flex items, just set margin-top: 50px for the child and remove align-items: center; for parent div

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by setting position absolute

```js
let div2 = document.querySelector("#div2");
div2.addEventListener("click", e => {
  div2.style.height = "300px";
})
```

```css
#div1 {
position:relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: red solid medium;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#div2 {
    position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  outline: blue solid medium;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky, but using an extra element this works. Definitely not responsive for various sizes though.

```js
let div2 = document.querySelector("#div2");
div2.addEventListener("click", e => {
  div2.style.height = "300px";
})
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: red solid medium;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#divc {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#div2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  outline: blue solid medium;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="divc"><div id="div2"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bad pratice to add html tags elements just to add a margin top between parent and child, why not using margin-top instead ?

Comment: Because you'll need to add margin-top and -bottom to work with flex

Answer (score 1):

```js
let div2 = document.querySelector("#div2");
// Keep the initial height of div2
const initialHeight = (div2.clientHeight);
div2.addEventListener("click", e => {
  // Add top and transform property
  const transformVal = initialHeight / 2;
  div2.style.transform = `translateY(-${transformVal}px)`;
  div2.style.top = '50%';
  div2.style.height = "300px";
})
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: red solid medium;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#div2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  outline: blue solid medium;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you could change the height of div1 to 100% so that it grows with div2 and use padding on div1 to maintain the area around div2.

```
#div1{
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 40px;
  outline: red solid medium;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try applying `transform-origin` property set to "`center top`" on the child and on the container too if needed.
Check out https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp for more help!

Comment: As the link states: "This property must be used together with the _transform_ property."

Answer (score 0):

The problem with keeping flex is that it adjusts to center things when you don't want to, you want the top of the blue square to stay at the same place.

This snippet removes flex and instead centers the blue element by moving it 50% from top and side and then back by half its height/width using a transform.

It also sets it positioned absolute so it doesn't affect the size of its parent when it expands.

A CSS variable is used to specify the initial height. This can then set the initial top position and that remains.

```js
let div2 = document.querySelector("#div2");
div2.addEventListener("click", e => {
  div2.style.height = "300px";
})
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: red solid medium;
  position: relative;
  --h: 100px;
  --w: 100px;
}

#div2 {
  height: var(--h);
  width: var(--w);
  outline: blue solid medium;
  top: calc((100% - var(--h)) / 2);
  left: calc((100% - var(--w)) / 2);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```